# Prettier + eslint line breaks

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier, eslint-config-airbnb, jsprettier

I am using eslint with VSCode 1.18.1 and the prettier/prettier extension 0.26.0 for VSCode. In my VSCode config I have `"prettier.eslintIntegration": true,`. My dependencies used to be:

```
"eslint": "^3.19.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^11.1.3",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
```

Typically prettier-eslint formatted like this:

```
return somePromise.then(result =>
  someOtherPromise(result, { foo: 'bar' })
);
```

Then I upgraded to:

```
"eslint": "^4.11.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^12.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
```

And now prettier-eslint is formatting files like this instead:

```
return somePromise.then(result =>
  someOtherPromise(result, { foo: 'bar' }));
```

This is a trivial example but if indentation goes a couple of levels deep then it becomes difficult to read. I prefer the old style.

Is it possible to achieve the previous formatting style with the upgraded dependencies?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Managed to fix it by adding the rules from [eslint-config-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier).

In my `.eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: ["airbnb-base", "prettier"],
  //...
}
```